# Reflection in Java (distinguishing two types)

Tags: java, reflection

In my program I'm passing **2 strings** to some method for an evaluation.
The method has to get the `Class` class for these strings(if it's a real class name!) and compare for their commonalities.
There can be 2 type of inputs for strings:

1. A Class name in Java API like "java.lang.Byte","java.lang.Math", etc.
2. Any other string possible like "some string", "hello", etc.

in my method which gets these two strings how could I understand whether it is of type 1 or 2 so not to get `Exception`?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt if there is a perfect condition to check this as "Hello" is as good a valid class name as java.lang.Byte. What you can do is validate string against the valid java identifiers http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8

So two checks :
1. Check for valid java class name.
2. Try Class.forName() to load the class. This will throough ClassNotFoundException if the class doesn't exist in the class path.

Have used a simple regex that I found in some other links to validate class name

```
String regexForBasicClassNameValidation = "([a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*\\.)*[a-zA-Z_$][a-zA-Z\\d_$]*" ;
     if(inputString.matches(regexForBasicClassNameValidation))
     {
     try {
            Class.forName(inputString) ;
            System.out.println("Valid class name");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Class name or class not found in classpath ");

    }
     }
     else
     {
     System.out.println("Not a class name");
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

[JavaDoc for Class.forName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Class clazz = null;
try 
{
    clazz = Class.forName(myString);    
} 
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
{
    System.out.println("This isn't a class");
}
```